# django not able to find git

Tags: django, git, windows-7, environment-variables

I'm trying to get Django development started on my Windows 7 partition and I'm finding that whenever I run a Django command I get:

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Often 3-4 times in a row but then the command seems to execute fine. While it doesn't seem to be affecting the execution of the commands, I don't like having errors thrown every time I do something, makes me nervous (and there's very possibly something I'm missing that's going wrong). I tried adding git to my environment variables but it didn't seem to work, here is the current PATH value.

```
 ;C:\Chocolatey\bin;C:\tools\mysql\current\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

Any additional suggestions to try are welcome. I'm using Windows 7 and the most recent version of Python, Django, and Git (just downloaded them today).

EDIT: I ran the commands again in response to some of your comments (thanks for those btw). Here's the output to python manage.py runserver

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in 
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 408, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 244, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 286, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 142, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 218, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 201, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 183, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1586, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1024, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1005, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 870, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 291, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 141, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 192, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 107, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

And here's the output to python manage.py syncdb

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 408, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 244, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 286, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 142, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 218, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 201, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 183, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1586, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1024, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1005, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 870, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 291, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 141, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 192, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 107, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Seems to be a result of missing MySQLdb. Does anyone have a link to this module? I can't find anything on Pypi called this *exactly*, I'm not sure which one it's looking for.

Comment: Django does not require or use git. You have something very messed up in your installation.

Comment: What command are you running? Because that guy is correct, git has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: I'm just running 'python manage.py runserver'

Comment: I updated my answer below based on the errors.

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that you overwrote your "manage.py" with something which tries to start git? Your manage.py should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourapp.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Or do you have a "git" commant in your settings.py?

EDIT after your error logs:
Did you install  the MySQL-python package (see docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#get-your-database-running) AND MySQLdb (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysqldb)? Both are required when using MySQL.

If yes, do you get the same results when switching to a sqlite database?

Comment: What I'm trying to run is a fresh Django filestructure. I observed the git not found error in it the initial syncdb.

Comment: which version of django are you using?

Comment: I downloaded the most recent version

Comment: Very strange - I just ade a file search in my whole django folder (recent check out as well) an found no git commands (only in the docs - which should have no side effects).

Comment: You say you observed the git not found erreor in syncdb as well - do yu get more error messages? Sounds quite strange...